# how to configure infinispan in jboss 7 for security-domain

Tags: java, jboss7.x, infinispan

In jboss 7.1 I want to use infinispan as cache-type of security-domain.
I set this configration in my standalone.xml :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="calypso-db-security-domain" cache-type="infinispan">
                    <authentication>
                      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapExtLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
......
 </security-domain>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.4">
            <cache-container name="security" aliases="standard-security-cache" default-cache="auth-cache">
              <local-cache name="auth-cache" batching="true">
              <expiration lifespan="0" max-idle="0"/>
              </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

what I don't understand is how do I connect by name the cache-type="infinispan" declaration with the specific cache-container of name="security" I defined .

Comment: does the connection done by the definition : default-cache="auth-cache" ?